# why the query is executed 76 times slower when I put it into function?

Tags: postgresql, query-planner, postgresql-12

When I put next query into function it goes 76times slower.
The only difference at plan is: bitmap-index scan VS index scan

Plan1: http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/plan_1562919134481
[image]

Plan2: http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/plan_1562918860704
[image]

[plan1](http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/plan_1562919134481)

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
        SELECT
            sum( t.group_suma ) OVER( PARTITION BY (t.o).id ) AS total_suma,
            *
        FROM (
            SELECT
             sum( ocd.item_cost     ) AS group_cost,
             sum( ocd.item_suma     ) AS group_suma,
             max( (ocd.ic).consumed ) AS consumed,
             (ocd.ic).consumed_period,
             ocd.o
            FROM order_cost_details( tstzrange( '2019-04-01', '2019-05-01' ) ) ocd
            GROUP BY ocd.o, (ocd.ic).consumed_period
        ) t
WHERE (t.o).id IN ( 6154 ) AND t.consumed_period @> '2019-04-01'::timestamptz
;
```

[Plan2](http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/plan_1562918860704)

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
SELECT * FROM order_total_suma( tstzrange( '2019-04-01', '2019-05-01' ) ) ots 
WHERE (ots.o).id IN ( 6154 ) AND ots.consumed_period @> '2019-04-01'::timestamptz
;
```

The function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION "order_total_suma" (in _target_range tstzrange default app_period())
 RETURNS    table(
        total_suma  double precision,
        group_cost  double precision,
        group_suma  double precision,
        consumed    double precision,
        consumed_period tstzrange,
        o order_bt
    )

 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
 AS $$
    SELECT
        sum( t.group_suma ) OVER( PARTITION BY (t.o).id ) AS total_suma,
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
         sum( ocd.item_cost     ) AS group_cost,
         sum( ocd.item_suma     ) AS group_suma,
         max( (ocd.ic).consumed ) AS consumed,
         (ocd.ic).consumed_period,
         ocd.o
        FROM order_cost_details( _target_range ) ocd
        GROUP BY ocd.o, (ocd.ic).consumed_period
    ) t
$$
;
```

**Why for the query inside function the filtering is done at the last subquery scan?**

[image]

Is it possible to do something so that they work equally?

**UPD**
Server version is `PostgreSQL 12beta2`
Because of 30000 characters limit I post plans [here](http://paste.scsys.co.uk/585294) and [here](https://pastebin.com/jRzKyFYq)

Comment: Can you please add the execution plans as [formatted plain text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) generated using **`explain (analzye, buffers, format text)`** The graphs hide too many details (and JSON isn't meant to be read and understood by humans)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: [Added](http://paste.scsys.co.uk/585294)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes. [Here](http://paste.scsys.co.uk/585295) is how I did that

Answer (score 2):

Thank to **RhodiumToad** from IRC:

> I suspect something's stopping the planner from being able to deduce that (t.o).id is safe to push through a GROUP BY ocd.o
>
> that might be fixable by making it a separate column of its own

Thus I additionally `GROUP BY` odc.id column. So my final query is:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT
                sum( t.group_suma ) OVER( PARTITION BY t.order_id ) AS total_suma,
--              sum( t.group_suma ) OVER( PARTITION BY (t.o).id ) AS total_suma,  -- For any WHERE this takes 2700ms
                *
            FROM (
                SELECT
                 sum( ocd.item_cost     ) AS group_cost,
                 sum( ocd.item_suma     ) AS group_suma,
                 max( (ocd.ic).consumed ) AS consumed,
                 (ocd.ic).consumed_period,
                 ocd.o,
                 (ocd.o).id as order_id
                FROM order_cost_details( tstzrange( '2019-04-01', '2019-05-01' ) ) ocd
                GROUP BY ocd.o, (ocd.o).id, (ocd.ic).consumed_period
            ) t
    ) t
    WHERE t.order_id = 6154 AND t.consumed_period @> '2019-04-01'::timestamptz       -- This takes 2ms
--  WHERE (t.o).id = 6154 AND t.consumed_period @> '2019-04-01'::timestamptz   -- This takes 2700ms
```

This change also makes call via function faster. I just need to sort via `order_id` field:

```sql
SELECT * FROM order_total_suma( tstzrange( '2019-04-01', '2019-05-01' ) ) ots 
-- This WHERE takes 2.5ms
WHERE ots.order_id IN ( 6154 ) AND ots.consumed_period @> '2019-04-01'::timestamptz
-- This WHERE takes 2500ms
-- WHERE (ots.o).id IN ( 6154 ) AND ots.consumed_period @> '2019-04-01'::timestamptz
```

Comment: Does that make query with function faster or your first query without function? From its content it appears as if it did not answer your question, but only improved initial query.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński: Yes. this change makes call via function faster. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The plans are quite different.

The problem is the misestimate in the result count of the join between `public.order_bt` and the `split_period` subquery. That causes the function `public.service_level_price` to be evaluated 2882 times rather than once, which is where the time is spent.

Not sure what to do about this (we don't have the view definition, and it's probably nasty). Raising the `COST` of the function probably doesn't help as the optimizer thinks it will call it only once.

Actually, the best bet may be

```
ALTER FUNCTION public.calc_item_suma ROWS 1;
```

which might get the optimizer to choose a different plan.