# JOIN vs SubQuery: Why subquery performance win when it should not?

Tags: postgresql, performance, subquery, left-join

[Recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57003113/4632019) I have asked about `Why select from function is slow?`.
But now when I `LEFT JOIN` this function it take 11500ms.
When I rewrite `LEFT JOIN` by `SubQuery` it took only 111ms

```sql
SELECT 
(SELECT next_ots FROM order_total_suma( next_range ) next_ots 
WHERE next_ots.order_id = ots.order_id  AND next_ots.consumed_period @> (ots.o).billed_to
) AS next_suma,  --<< this took only 111ms. See plan
ots.* FROM (
    SELECT  
        tstzrange(
          NULLIF( (ots.o).billed_to, 'infinity' ),
          NULLIF( (ots.o).billed_to +p.interval, 'infinity' )
        ) as next_range,
     ots.*
    FROM order_total_suma() ots
    LEFT JOIN period p ON p.id = (ots.o).period_id
) ots
--LEFT JOIN order_total_suma( next_range ) next_ots ON next_ots.order_id = 6154 
--  AND next_ots.consumed_period @> (ots.o).billed_to --<< this is fine. plan is not posted
--LEFT JOIN order_total_suma( next_range ) next_ots ON next_ots.order_id = ots.order_id  
--  AND next_ots.consumed_period @> (ots.o).billed_to --<< this takes 11500ms. See Plan
WHERE ots.order_id IN ( 6154, 10805 )
```

Attached [plans](https://pastebin.com/N6DnGbsX)

While googling I have found [this blog post](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/postgresql-performance-considerations)

> In most cases, **joins are also a better solution than subqueries** — Postgres will even internally “rewrite” a subquery, creating a join, whenever possible, but this of course increases the time it takes to come up with the query plan

Many SO question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39588846/4632019)

> A LEFT [OUTER] JOIN can be faster than an equivalent subquery because the server might be able to optimize it better—a fact **that is not specific to MySQL Server alone.**

So why `LEFT JOIN`ing function is significantly slower in compare to `SubQuery`?
Is there a way to make `LEFT JOIN` take time equally to `SubQuery`?

Comment: What is the volatility of your function set to?  STABLE?  Was it not specified?

Comment: @Jeremy: Function volatility is `STABLE`.